# Long range tracking of markers with Qualcomm AR SDK for Android

Tags: android, sdk, augmented-reality

Is it possible to improve the tracking on long distances / ranges?
With long range I mean around 4-6 meters.
When I move away from the image or marker with the phone suddenly the tracking is lost although the image quality is no that bad (especially the markers are clearly visible).

Can I anything do to better track Markers at long distances? Without printing the markers on DINA 3 ^^

Answer (score 2):

The rule of thumb with fiducial markers (like AR-Toolkit style) is they're trackable to ~10x the marker width. I assume that the same is the case for the edge markers in the Qualcomm SDK since they "track" the same outer rectangle corners.  The implementation is based on TU Graz's Studierstube which was published at academic conferences, so searching for their publications might yield hard values. Natural feature markers can be tracked further, but not to a precise definition of "further" - it depends heavily on the features.

Edit: I found the paper where they presented frame and split markers, but they didn't evaluate tracking distances there.